# Read first field of json

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, junit

I'm running a JUnit test and here is my current expected and actual result:

```
Expected :"resultCode":"SUCCESS"
Actual   :{"resultCode":"SUCCESS","data":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJlbWFpbEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbCI6ImVtYWlsQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoicGFzc3dvcmQifQ.lKxvMPhsJAjFqOryb-0cUgBh-C9jjUfatydX42Jos5clkn9N9YA01DRzZX0XbhdYXJaacUfx8GwRsFGsLjGcxg"}
```

I need to set my expected result to read just the first field of the actual result json because the data token is dynamic and cant be the same every test.
My current code is:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/auth/logIn")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(json))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
        .andExpect(content().string("\"resultCode\":\"SUCCESS\"")).andReturn();
```

I guess I need to do the changes in the last line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant something like this:

```
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.resultCode", is("SUCCESS")))
```

since json is a key-value map, you should not assume order of fields in it